# Goals not being retrieved from Sitecore xDB ( MongoDB )

Tags: xdb, aggregation

I upgraded my site from Sitecore 7.5 to 8.1,  and following is the code that I'm using to retrieve the page events:

```cs
foreach (PageData page in args.Context.Visit.Pages)
{
    if (page.PageEvents != null)
    {
         foreach (var pageEvent in page.PageEvents)
         {
             if (pageEvent.IsGoal)
                Log.Error("Goal: " + pageEvent.Name.ToString(), "PageEventProcessor");
         }
     }
}
```

the page events are being retrieved except the goals, Although I can see the following data in the interaction collection in MongoDB:

```json
"PageEvents" : [
    {
        "Name" : "Mobile Click",
        "Timestamp" : NumberLong(0),
        "Data" : "Mohammed Test",
        "DataKey" : "650fce89-87bb-4768-ab40-8bc988d7a729",
        "Text" : "Location Name and other information",
        "PageEventDefinitionId" : LUUID("e7798282-5362-af4d-80ce-07055fcf3b86"),
        "IsGoal" : true,
        "DateTime" : ISODate("2015-08-23T16:12:21.686Z"),
        "Value" : 10
    }
],
```

Am I doing something wrong in the retrieving code? Is there another code I should use? Any suggestions?.

Comment: What is the template of your goal item?

Comment: It is a goal template /sitecore/templates/System/Analytics/Goal,

Comment: Have you made sure it's the same visit you are checking?

Comment: Actually I want to go through all visits, How I can do that?

Comment: Well because I imagine the current visit (args.Context.Visit) is not the one you registered the goal on because the session needs to die before it gets added to the db right?

Comment: Which pipeline are you using with your processor?

Comment: I'm using the "interactions" pipeline.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting page events with debugger, instead of just logging errors?

Comment: Yes, There are no "IsGoal" events coming.

Comment: Yeah, but maybe the goals are coming, just with `IsGoal` set to `false`? That would indicate some sort of a bug in xDB.

Comment: When you have created the Goal, have you checked the options under Customer Intelligence Options?


You have Track as latest event and Show in events.


Track as latest event - Once the goal is triggered by the contact (visitor) it appears in the Latest Events in the Contact tab.


Show in events - When triggered by the contact (visitor) it appears in the list of Events under the Visits tab.

Comment: @MohammedSyam This won't address the question but to get all historic visit of the contact you can try something like below from Habitat  `Tracker.Current.Contact.LoadKeyBehaviorCache();
      var keyBehaviourCache = Tracker.Current.Contact.GetKeyBehaviorCache();
      foreach (var cachedGoal in keyBehaviourCache.Goals)
      { //Logic here }`

Comment: @MohammedSyam Is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the OP, the comments, your code and Sitecore's, I believe that this issue is likely caused by a bug in the `PageEvent.IsGoal` property, whereby the property is not being correctly set to `true` for events that are goals. I have not yet confirmed this bug, but if I am correct then the following should help you work around the issue:

### Solution

Try changing your code to the following:

```
foreach (PageData page in args.Context.Visit.Pages)
{
    if (page.PageEvents != null && 0 < page.PageEvents.Count)
    {
         foreach (var pageEvent in page.PageEvents)
         {
             var pageEventItem = pageEvent.PageEventDefinitionId != Guid.Empty 
                 ? Tracker.DefinitionItems.Goals[pageEvent.PageEventDefinitionId] 
                 : Tracker.DefinitionItems.Goals[pageEvent.Name];

             if (pageEventItem == null || !pageEventItem.IsGoal) 
             {
                 throw new Exception("I must be null because I definitely should be a goal. Still I should never be thrown because I came from the Goals property of the trackers definition items");
             }   

             Log.Info("Goal: " + pageEvent.Name.ToString(), "PageEventProcessor");

             // now do something with your goal
         }
     }
}
```

Notice that in the above solution, I am using the `pageEventItem.IsGoal` property instead of the `pageEvent.IsGoal` property. I have not sufficiently tested this to figure out if the problem is simply with the `PageEvent.IsGoal` flag is not set when you check it, but I expect that to be the case. Regardless, the `PageEventItem.IsGoal` should be accurate and more reliable, as that property is read directly from the item's field.

### Arrival at Solution

While I am still working to figure out if this is actually a bug in xDB, I came to this solution by looking at how Sitecore aggregates goals in the `<interactions>` pipeline.

Remember that a [Goal](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/campaigns/goals__events/goals) is really a conversion, and since there weren't any processors with "Goal" in the name, I had a look at the `Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.Pipeline.ConversionsProcessor`.

After reviewing the processor I realized that Sitecore's approach was nearly identical to yours though slightly different - Sitecore's code uses the item's field to determine if it's actually a goal. Since checking the value of that field should be more reliable than a property that may or may not have been correctly set on a C# object, I am left to infer that the issue is likely a bug in Sitecore with the `PageEvent.IsGoal` property and that you should work around the issue by using the `PageEventItem.IsGoal` property, instead.

### Next Steps

The first thing that I recommend you do is try the above workaround. Next, I would get in touch with Sitecore Support and show them what you've tried and what you are seeing. They should be able to provide further assistance, in addition to documenting and fixing the bug, if confirmed.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

For performance reasons, interaction details (like page events) are only loaded when needed.

Play around with the following in order to load historical data:

```
var contactRepository = Factory.CreateObject("tracking/contactRepository", true) as ContactRepository;
var interactions = contactRepository.LoadHistoricalInteractions(arg.Session.Contact.ContactId, 10);
```

Comment: The OP's code is in a custom `interactions` processor. So there won't be any session. And there will already be a loaded visit in the pipeline args. So I don't think your code will be helpful.